# ViewController going to previous ViewController by swapping on the screen

Tags: ios, segue, viewcontroller, navigationview

Say I have two viewController, `AViewController` and `BViewController`. `AViewController` is Embedded in `NavigationController` (From menu "Editor > Embedded In > NavigationController"). And from a **button action** in `AViewController` it push user to the `BViewController` (Using segue). Now user can come back to the `AViewController` by press `backButton` in `BViewController`.

But the strange thing is, in `BViewController`, If I swap the screen from left to right, it seems like removing the view from the stack and showing `AViewController`. I don't want this swap. I want to use only back button to go previous viewController which is `BViewController` in this case. How can I stop this swap?

Thanks in advance.

**PS : I don't have any type of gesture added in the entire project**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AViewController` add in `ViewDidLoad` the line below to disable interactive pop for navigation controller. Then everything should be like you want.

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
```

Comment: Yup, this is what I was trying to find out. Two more question. 01. Is this option also available, may be in Storyboard : "Attributes Inspector"? 02. How can I set this in AppDelegate, so that I don't have to add this in each ViewController class.
Thanks

Comment: @Tulon add it only in `rootViewController` of your `NavigationController`. There is no need to add it to every single new `ViewController` because the NC is shared, so simple set this property once and it will work for every single VS in this specific NC.

It's not possible to disable interactive pop from storyboard.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Enable swapped navigation

This one work for me !!! Good Luck !

```
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
```